# AppleScript - How to append text to end of a file

Tags: text, append, applescript, rdp

I'd like to have a script that I can run where it basically takes the .rdp file that I have selected in finder, and append a line of text to the end of it.

e.g

I download a .rdp file to use in Microsoft Remote Access and to speed up my workflow I'd like to append the text 'Use Multimon:i:1' at the end before I launch it so that I don't have to open the preferences each time.

I'm not too familiar with AppleScript so would appreciate any advice on how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that .RDP files are saved in plain text format.  If this is the case, using the `do shell script` command in an AppleScript, appending text to a file is fairly simple.  This following AppleScript code should work for you.

Paste this following code into a new Script Editor.app document. Then
with your .RDP file currently selected in Finder, run the code in Script Editor.app and it will append   the text to your file.

```
property addText : "Use Multimon:i:1"

tell application "Finder" to set selectedFile to POSIX path of ((get selection) as alias)

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of addText & " >> " & quoted form of selectedFile
```

Comment: This is the first solution that popped into my head, to run a bash script to append the text. OP can take this solution further by using Automator to create a Quick Action workflow. The trigger is when you select a file in Finder, run the above AppleScript (with little modification). In that way, you just have to right click on the RDP file in finder, and the script will be available for you to run.

Answer (score 1):

This currently works for a selected file with the extension 'txt'. Test it and if it works for you, edit it to your desired extension.

The 'if' statements are to ensure that you don't accidentally append the text to a binary file which could corrupt that file. The 'return' means that your text will appear on its own line. If you don't want that, remove 'return & '. For details on 'open for access', please see the [Language Guide: Commands Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW31). On the same page, you can find 'close access'.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set tFile to selection as alias
    
    if name extension of tFile is "txt" then
        set corR to true
    else
        display alert "Are you sure you've selected the correct file?"
        set corR to false
    end if
end tell

if corR is true then
    set ab to open for access tFile with write permission
    write return & "Use Multimon:i:1" to ab starting at eof
    close access ab
end if
```